# Sending data to a UITableViewCell - data won't send

Tags: ios, objective-c

Every time I try to send an array to this custom tableview cell, the array doesn't send (as is evident by the array.count = 0, while it should be 9).

Here is my `cell.h`:

```
@interface Scell : UITableViewCell

...
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *lineInfo;

@end
```

`cell.m`:

```
@implementation Scell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self)
    {
        self.lineInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        //set up labels here, etc.

        NSLog(@"Lines count: %li", self.lineInfo.count);
    }

    return self;
}
```

And here is where I try to send the data.

`setup.m`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Make cell 
    Scell *cell = (Scell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    object *temp = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //labels, etc.

    NSLog(@"count: %li", temp.lineInfo.count);
    cell.lineInfo = temp.lineInfo;
    return cell;
}
```

Any idea why it's not sending? The NSLog in setup.m displays 9, but the one in Scell displays 0.

Answer (score 0):

In cell.m, lines count will be printed when the cell is initialised so at that time there are no values in this array that's why it is printing zero.

From cellForRowAtIndexPath in setup.m, the lineInfo of temp is assigned to cell's lineInfo property. So because of this the cellForRowAtIndexPath prints the correct count but the initWithStyle displays 0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @BhargavR. The error makes sense to me now, but as far as fixing goes, where would be better to initialize lineInfo?

Comment: I am not sure what is the reason to send the array of data to another array in the cell because whenever you want to access that data in the view controller(where table view is added) it would be available in self.array. If there could be some more clarity about this, it would be great.

Comment: I need to send the array to the cell because I need to create a UIView in the cell out of elements in the array... ie the array might have "red" and "blue" elements, and I need to display those two colors in a UIView located inside the cell... Although I wonder if there is a better way to go about it now that I think about it

Comment: You can directly set the colors in the view inside the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method also as all the views inside the cells will be accessible here So I think there is no need to pass the array details to the cell array.